# BlobContainerClient - Get all blobs in root

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm using [`BlobContainerClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient?view=azure-dotnet) like so:

`var blobs = _blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync(BlobTraits.Metadata, BlobStates.None, prefix: "");`

When a blob is placed in the container it will be processed and later moved to a sub-folder. It works great, but I each time I use `GetBlobsAsync` it will also give me the blobs in the sub-folders. **Is there a way to only get the blobs in the root folder?**

I know that I can get metadata of them all and then filter them out on the client. But after a month or two it will be a lot of blobs and I eventually the payload will increase.

Answer (score 1):

For this, you would want to use [`BlobContainerClient.GetBlobsByHierarchy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobsbyhierarchy?view=azure-dotnet) method. This will return both blobs and virtual folders. You need not define the `prefix` because you are only interested in getting blobs at the root level.

You can filter the result on [`BlobHierarchyItem.IsBlob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobhierarchyitem.isblob?view=azure-dotnet#azure-storage-blobs-models-blobhierarchyitem-isblob) property to only list the blobs and not virtual folders.

Comment: What am I missing? When using `GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync` the first item I get is `myfolder/some_blob.json`. That would require me to iterate through all the items anyway?

Comment: Did you specify any prefix?

Comment: I've tried without `prefix` and with empty `prefix`

Comment: My problem is not to get all the items in the root, but to get them and let the server do the filtering instead of the client. I would like to avoid unnecessary reads.

Comment: Server side filtering to only return blobs is not supported. You’ll get both blobs and virtual folders. You’ll need to do filtering on the client side only.